# Html + js ; Populated Select

Tags: javascript, html, css, select

I need a simple conditional select for my html form like this example (not have any JS and CSS yet).

**Logic** : if Category1 selected for any `'value'` or any `'comment'`, it will only show on select **Category2**, **Category3** and **Category4** which is have only same `'rel'` tag from **Category1**.

```html
<select id='category1' required>
  <option rel='A' value='value1'>Option One</option>
  <option rel='A' value='value2'>Option Two</option>
  <option rel='C' value='value3'>Option Three</option>
  <option rel='B' value='value4'>Option Four</option>
  <option rel='C' value='value5'>Option Five</option>
</select>

<select id='category2' required>
  <option rel='A' value='value11'>Sub A</option>
  <option rel='A' value='value12'>Sub B</option>
  <option rel='A' value='value13'>Sub C</option>
  <option rel='B' value='value14'>Sub D</option>
  <option rel='B' value='value15'>Sub E</option>
  <option rel='C' value='value16'>Sub F</option>
  <option rel='C' value='value17'>Sub G</option>
  <option rel='A' value='value18'>Sub H</option>
</select>

<select id='category3' required>
  <option rel='A' value='AAA'>Some A</option>
  <option rel='B' value='BBB'>Some B</option>
  <option rel='C' value='CCC'>Some C</option>
</select>

<select id='category4'>
  <option rel='A' value='DDD'>Other A</option>
  <option rel='B' value='EEE'>Other B</option>
  <option rel='B' value='FFF'>Other C</option>
  <option rel='B' value='GGG'>Other C</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for; at least the start of it.

https://jsfiddle.net/v5xvcsub/

```
document.getElementById("category1").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var selectedRel = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('rel');

  var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
  for (index = 0; index < selects.length; ++index) {
    // deal with inputs[index] element.
    select = selects[index];
    if (select.id !== "category1") {
      var options = select.options;
      for (index in options) {
        try {
          if (options[index].getAttribute('rel') == selectedRel) {
            options[index].style.display = null;
          } else {
            options[index].style.display = "none";
          }
        } catch (e) {
          //fail silently for invalid input
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

When an item in category1 is selected, it'll loop through the other selects and then loop through their respective options.

Answer (score 0):

It is working now, thanks for the "trigger".

And special thanks to Bro Arga, for the completion.

```js
document.getElementById("category1").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var selectedRel = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('rel');

  var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
  for (index = 0; index < selects.length; ++index) {
    // deal with inputs[index] element.
    select = selects[index];
    if (select.id !== "category1") {
      var options = select.options;
      console.log(select);
      for (idx in options) {
        console.log(options[idx]);
        try {
          if (options[idx].getAttribute('rel') == selectedRel) {
            options[idx].style.display = null;
          } else {
            options[idx].style.display = "none";
          }
        } catch (e) {
          //fail silently for invalid input
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<select id='category1' required>
  <option rel='A' value='value1'>Option One</option>
  <option rel='A' value='value2'>Option Two</option>
  <option rel='C' value='value3'>Option Three</option>
  <option rel='B' value='value4'>Option Four</option>
  <option rel='C' value='value5'>Option Five</option>
</select>

<select id='category2' required>
  <option rel='A' value='value11'>Sub A</option>
  <option rel='A' value='value12'>Sub B</option>
  <option rel='A' value='value13'>Sub C</option>
  <option rel='B' value='value14'>Sub D</option>
  <option rel='B' value='value15'>Sub E</option>
  <option rel='C' value='value16'>Sub F</option>
  <option rel='C' value='value17'>Sub G</option>
  <option rel='A' value='value18'>Sub H</option>
</select>

<select id='category3' required>
  <option rel='A' value='AAA'>Some A</option>
  <option rel='B' value='BBB'>Some B</option>
  <option rel='C' value='CCC'>Some C</option>
</select>

<select id='category4'>
  <option rel='A' value='DDD'>Other A</option>
  <option rel='B' value='EEE'>Other B</option>
  <option rel='B' value='FFF'>Other C</option>
  <option rel='B' value='GGG'>Other C</option>
</select>
```